# Leading (-) ve sign is not getting removed in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove leading - ve sign along with non numerical values  from the row values where present, But when any - ve values is present in the column it gives the same as it is , Please Suggest.

**Input Data**

```
col1           col2  

-122.45         NaN
Ninety Five    3585/-
9987           178@#?
225 Nine       1983.86
Twelve         7363*
```

**Output Data:**

```
col1           col2  

122.45         NaN
NaN            3585
9987           178
225            1983.86
NaN            7363
```

**Code i am using**

```
df[['col1','col2']]=df[['col1','col2']].replace('([^\d\.])', '', regex=True).replace('',float("NaN"),regex=True).astype(float)
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Just chain `.abs()` to your current method after `astype(float)`

Comment: @Psidom -  I am using the above line of code to remove all non Numeric characters but when we have any Values leading by - ve sign , It's not removing the - ve sign . Please Suggesst.

Comment: What is `- ve sign`  ? It seems to me working as expected. Removing all non numeric characters or do you want to keep the leading `-` ?